# Is it idiomatic to say (as word choice and usage) "I read some question marks on their faces because of latest news"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, sentence

Lets say that I want to underline that people have some concerns because of the latest news

Is it idiomatically correct to say "I read some question marks on their faces because of latest news in a sentence?

Comment: "I noticed some questioning expressions."

Comment: Unless the many people share a single face, it should be *their* ***faces***.

Comment: ah yes! thanks for the correction

Comment: 14 000 Google hits for 'question marks on their faces' shows that you could certainly use this, but 350 000 Google hits for 'puzzled looks' shows that this is far more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinAshworth! could you please give me an example of "question marks on their faces" in a sentence referring to my sentence above?

Comment: Semi-randomly taken from a quick Google search for "question marks on their faces" (the double inverted commas force the exact phrase in a Google search): 'Nandini joined Shaina and both of them bent down and stared at Amaan with big question marks on their faces.' [_Nandini joined Shaina and both of them bent down and stared at Amaan with big question marks on their faces._ –  Ishan Majumdar]

Answer (score 3):

**"puzzled looks"** seems to be the phrase you're looking for.

"the latest news was met with **puzzled looks**.

> **puzzled** - confused because you do not understand something. - [**CD**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/puzzled)
>
> - He had a puzzled look on his face.
> - I'm still puzzled as to why she said that.
> - I'm really puzzled that I haven't heard from Liz for so long.

"baffled" or "perplexed" might fit.

Comment: Exactly. This is what I am looking for. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

As in:    [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/flummoxed)

"I saw many **flummoxed** faces because of latest news."

> perplexed or bewildered

As in: [ChinaDaily.com](http://www.chinadaily.com.cn/a/201903/14/WS5c894940a3106c65c34ee78a.html)

> Back in 2014, if you had hit the streets of Europe or the United
>   States and asked a random stranger to list some well-known Chinese
>   brands, you might have seen some **flummoxed faces**.

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer

Comment: About 350 Google hits for 'flummoxed faces', 14 000 for 'question marks on their faces', and 350 000 for 'puzzled looks'. OP would be better quitting while they're ahead.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth 'for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts'

Comment: Serious language enthusiasts would recognise that OP is looking for an idiomatic expression.

Comment: An expression can be flummoxed. A person can be flummoxed. A face… not so much. It sounds definitively _un_-idiomatic to me to describe a face as flummoxed.